# Why I get this error: No DLLs were found in the Waterfall procedure

Tags: windows, windows-xp

We have an Olympus microscope with a camera, which comes with software. We have normally installed the program from Olympus on Windows XP SP3 without any problems.

After that when we want to open the program, it gives us this error:

> No DLLs were found in the Waterfall procedure

After that I click OK, and then we receive this error:

> LoadLibary (SisMain.dll) failed!

We have contacted Olympus, and they told us to install IPP_5_4_3_Runtime.ZIP from [this page](https://www.olympus-sis.com/corp/2417.htm#24).

When I click on the `setup.exe` file, and when the setup starts, a few seconds later for no reason the installation disappears. So I don't whether the installation was successful or not.

However when I try to open the program again, it gives us the same error. While I wait for the answer from Olympus, I hope someone can help.

- What does IPP_5_4_3_Runtime do?
- Can we simply copy/paste the missing DLL files or is there another solution for that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Performance_Primitives

Comment: The default installation folder for [Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-install-guide) is `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools` - check if it is there. If yes, check that it is in your PATH environment. If no, download again and try installing.

Comment: ok. i will try to find it. also can i transfer files from old pc to this new pc. because on old pc everything is working. both computers have the same OS.